# Select from two tables which have no relation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I don't know if it is possible or not. If possible, please help me to resolve this.

I have two tables, `table1` and `table2`:

```
        table1                                table2
 column1     column2                column3            column4      
    1           2                      A                   B              
    3           4                      C                   D
```

There is no relation between `table1` and `table2`. I want to execute a query so that my output looks like this:

**Output table**:

```
  column1      column2       column3       column4
     1            2             A             B
     1            2             C             D
     3            4             A             B
     3            4             C             D
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this? We are using SQL Server 2005.

Thanks,
Kartic

Comment: MySQL Server 2005? Are you sure it's not MS SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a `cross join`, which produces a Cartesian product of all the records in each of the tables.  The best way to do this is explicitly, with the `cross join` syntax:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

Note that if either table is empty, then you will not get any rows back.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2
```

It's called a cross join, or cartesian product.

You can add additional filtering or join conditions using `WHERE`.

Comment: I assume that both of these answers were downvoted for not using the ANSI SYNTAX for CROSS JOIN? Seems like this one was harsh as it will give the correct answer.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard. Please don't suggest stuff that's been outdated for **more than 20 years** now.

Comment: Who cares. He asks about MS SQL. Not SQL. And originally, it was even MySQL which has , as preferred join syntax. I'm really tired of this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cross join.

```
select t1.*,t2.* from table1 t1
Cross Join table2 t2;
```